# Ideas for checking a successful login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I'm submitting a form with:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:self.username forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:self.password forKey:@"password"];
[request startSynchronous];
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
```

The last line is okay for printing the response string but how to get for example the absolute url of the response url? I need that because I need to check if url's ending in `"/login/"`.

Any other ideas for checking a successful login?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try `NSLog(@"%@", [request responseHeaders]);` ?

Comment: Yes and it prints the headers dictionary. But there's not key that satisfies my needs.

Comment: The obvious answer is request.url, but presumably you've already tried that and it doesn't do what you want for some reason. This is pretty much impossible to answer as it's entirely dependent on how the webserver/website has been setup.

Comment: @JosephH thanks, request.url satisfies my needs. I did't know that `request.url` changes based on redirects. -- if you post an answer I'll be happy to accept it as correct answer.

Comment: @FredCollins Ah, okay, I guess the fact that it changes isn't so obvious :-) Have posted as an answer!

Comment: Thanks again. The doc says: `It’s best to avoid using the request’s URL to distinguish between different requests in your delegate methods, because the URL property can change when a request is redirected. If you really want to use the request URL, use [request originalURL] instead - this will always be the first url the request connected to.` Bye!

Comment: Why are you trying to do it this way? Wouldn't it be better to have the server return a boolean, such as `{"success": true}` to indicate your login succeeded? I think it would be safer to look at the raw HTTP headers to detect the redirect, but I don't know how to do this with ASIHTTPRequest (it's easy with NSURLRequest however).

Comment: Yes probably it's better. If the login is successful the server automatically redirects to `/`. I need to see how to set an extra json to the `return HttpResponseRedirect('/')`. I use Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.url` will contain the final URL for any request, including any redirections that have happened.